# Passing variables rather than hard coded data to paypal buy now button

Tags: php, html, paypal

I am working on a paypal button and I am trying to figure out how to pass variables to paypal to bounce them back to my handler. I currently have the following in my paypal button code.

```
<input name="custom" type="hidden" value='{"firstName" : "Lucas","lastName" : "Harvmaster","email" : "shrike321@hotmail.com","companyName" : "Matchbox","password" : "123Cupcakes"}'>
```

This works, but isn't espectially dynamic. I am unsure how to pass that data as variables I collect from the user rather than hard coded. I don't think I can just create fillable spots in the form because it needs to be added together and formatted to send as the custom variable spot for paypal.

Edit: I saw some folks do something like this, but I wasn't quite able to get it working.

```
<?php
    $firstName = "Lucas";
    $lastName = "Harvmaster";
    $email = "shrike321@hotmail.com";
    $companyName = "Matchbox";
    $password = "123Cupcakes";
?>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input name="custom" type="hidden" value='{"firstName" : <?php echo $firstName ?>,"lastName" : "Harvmaster","email" : "shrike321@hotmail.com","companyName" : "Matchbox","password" : "123Cupcakes"}'>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="89924XE27QRNY">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish this? Can we see your JavaScript? The community won't write your code *for* you, and wouldn't even be able to when you haven't even provided a sample of your HTML to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="89924XE27QRNY">
```

This is a hosted button, it doesn't use dynamic variables stored in the PayPal account (editable via https://www.paypal.com/buttons )

While it's possible to create a [non-hosted HTML button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) with other set variables, there is no reason to do so.

Instead, use a smart button: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

You can personalize one via https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart

Then edit the `purchase_units` object to describe what it's selling. Your own data can be set in the `custom_id` string as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request

Comment: The current hosted button that I'm using does seem to take the variable that I'm passing in custom, that isn't the issue I'm grappling with. The struggle for me is that I'm unsure how to set up the custom_id string to be sent to Paypal. I've set it up as something my handler can decode as a json, but I'm unsure how to take fields for the data I need to send and use them to make the custom_id string.

Comment: You can pass additional variables on a hosted button, yes--but not override existing ones.  To your struggle, it seems you're asking about how to concatenate strings in PHP. Use the `.` operator.

Comment: better yet, make a PHP array and then `json_encode()`

Comment: Ooh, a PHP array with `json_encode()` sounds like it might solve my problem! However, this doesn't quite seem to have worked `<input name="custom" type="hidden" value="<?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>">`

Comment: To clarify my handler `file_put_contents()` the custom variable in the ipn and the file is empty using the method above.

Comment: Wild, I was fiddling with it and it just seemed to have started working? I'm honestly not sure what I changed. Perhaps it was using single quotes instead of double quotes? Anyway, thanks for the help! Using the json_encode helped a lot. It has somewhat spawned other questions, but they are sufficiently deviated from this that I'll probably create a new question if I can't get them solved myself.